# Linux script for create the user on remote server

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I've been able to create a user on the remote server without a problem with the below command.

```
ssh -i /home/centos/dummy.pem centos@host_ip  'sudo useradd -s /bin/bash -m testuser'
```

If I try to create a user on a remote server with shell script, it is throwing the error, passing the host_user, host_ip, and new_user argument like 
`./test.sh "host_user"  "host_ip" "new_user"`

```
#!/bin/bash

#Remote server login user
echo host_user=$1

#Remote server hostname
host_name=$2

#user name
user_name=$3

#user public key
#pub_key=$4

ssh $host_user@$host_name -i /home/centos/dummy.pem 'sudo useradd -s /bin/bash -m $user_name'
```

Expected:
new user on a remote server.

Actual result:

```
Usage: useradd [options] LOGIN
       useradd -D
       useradd -D [options]

Options:
  -b, --base-dir BASE_DIR       base directory for the home directory of the
                                new account
  -c, --comment COMMENT         GECOS field of the new account
  -d, --home-dir HOME_DIR       home directory
```

And also tried with "-D" in the script but no luck.

Comment: See quoting https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes

Comment: "sudo useradd -s /bin/bash -m $user_name" Use double-quotes instead of a glitch '

Comment: Paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: able to create user after replacing with  Use double-quotes. thank you so much @GoinOff

Comment: when script variables are within a glitch '. variable value substitution will not take place.

Comment: Thanks for the info